# Is is possible to create two data frames in a single work flow with magrittr?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

Getting started with the [magrittr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/index.html) pipe operators and was curious if two data frames could be created in a single flow.  For example, it would be helpful to produce a non-aggregated data frame for plotting and an aggregated data frame to order factors ([aggregate ordering example](https://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/how-do-i-re-arrange-ordering-a-plot-revisited/)).

Here is a rather contrived example, that illustrates the question:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2) # msleep

vore_count <- 
  na.exclude(msleep) %>%
  group_by(vore, order) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup()

agg <- vore_count %>% 
  spread(vore, count)
```

Could both `vore_count` *and* `agg` be generated in the same flow?

I've tried the following (as well as using %T>%), which obviously don't work.

```
vore_count <- 
  na.exclude(msleep) %>%
  group_by(vore, order) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
      agg <- spread(vore, count)
```

Comment: What packages are you using besides `magrittr`? Is `spread` a UDF or is it from some other package?

Comment: @Minnow `?spread` is from `tidyr`

Comment: `msleep` is in `ggplot2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `list()` in the pipe then concatenate `agg` after evaluation of the first data.frame.  Here I just use `mtcars`.  The result is a named list of two data frames.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

na.exclude(mtcars) %>%
    group_by(cyl, disp) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    list(cyl_count = .) %>%
    c(list(agg = spread(.$cyl_count, cyl, count)))
```

If you want to assign these to the global environment, you can add the following line to the end of the pipe

```
... %>%
    list2env(globalenv())

ls(pattern = "agg|cyl_count")
# [1] "agg"       "cyl_count"
```

Answer (score 6):

Side-assignment is easier with `pipeR`.

```
library(pipeR)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2) 
library(tidyr)
na.exclude(msleep) %>>%
  group_by(vore, order) %>>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>>%
  ungroup() %>>%
  (~ vore_count) %>>% 
  spread(vore, count)%>>% 
  (~ agg)
```

Answer (score 3):

Although I can understand the temptation, IMO only one assignment should be made from one workflow/pipeline. It's cleaner, easier to read, and better practice. Each pipeline should ideally have one purpose only. One input, one output.

Comment: Advice well-taken. I was curious if anyone would recommend against it.  I suppose you'd have built this feature if it were a good idea.

Comment: @Minnow it has been requested a few times, but I am not too happy encouraging this. It is also possible to do using a combination of `%T>%` and `assign`, although you need to have a reference to the environment. I am thinking of making the environment easily accessible later on.

@AK_ IMO it is often a better answer to guide good practice.. But you're right, point taken.